# ZF2 phpunit Zend Logger

Tags: php, zend-framework2, phpunit

I am trying to write unit test for my application. which as logging the information functionality.

To start with i have service called LogInfo, this how my class look like

```
use Zend\Log\Logger;
class LogInfo {
 $logger = new Logger;
 return $logger;
}
```

I have another class which will process data. which is below.

```
class Processor 
{
    public $log;

    public function processData($file)
    {
        $this->log = $this->getLoggerObj('data');
        $this->log->info("Received File");
    }
     public function getLoggerObj($logType)
    {
        return $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Processor\Service\LogInfo')->logger($logType);
    }
}
```

here i am calling service **Loginfo** and using it and writing information in a file.

now i need to write phpunit for class **Processor**

below is my unit test cases

```
class ProcessorTest{
    public function setUp() {
    $mockLog = $this->getMockBuilder('FileProcessor\Service\LogInfo', array('logger'))->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();
    $mockLogger = $this->getMockBuilder('Zend\Log\Logger', array('info'))->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();

    $serviceManager = new ServiceManager();
        $serviceManager->setService('FileProcessor\Service\LogInfo', $mockLog);
        $serviceManager->setService('Zend\Log\Logger', $mockLogger);

        $this->fileProcessor = new Processor();
        $this->fileProcessor->setServiceLocator($serviceManager);
    }

    public function testProcess() {
        $data = 'I have data here';
        $this->fileProcessor->processData($data);
    }
}
```

I try to run it, i am getting an error **"......PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function info() on a non-object in"**

i am not sure , how can i mock Zend logger and pass it to class.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting what the call to `get('Processor\Service\LogInfo')` in the `getLoggerObj` function returns to you during the test-case?

Answer (score 0):

Lets check out some of your code first, starting with the actual test class `ProcessorTest`. This class constructs a `new ServiceManager()`. This means you are going to have to do this in every test class, which is not efficient ([DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)). I would suggest constructing the `ServiceMananger` like the [Zend Framework 2 documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/tutorials/unittesting.html) describes in the headline [Bootstrapping your tests](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/tutorials/unittesting.html#bootstrapping-your-tests). The following code is the method we are interested in.

```
public static function getServiceManager()
{
    return static::$serviceManager;
}
```

Using this approach makes it possible to obtain the instance of `ServiceManager` through `Bootstrap::getServiceManager()`. Lets refactor the test class using this method.

```
class ProcessorTest
{
    protected $serviceManager;
    protected $fileProcessor;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->serviceManager = Bootstrap::getServiceManager();
        $this->serviceManager->setAllowOverride(true);
        $fileProcessor = new Processor();
        $fileProcessor->setServiceLocator($this->serviceManager);
        $this->fileProcessor = $fileProcessor;
    }

    public function testProcess()
    {
        $mockLog = $this->getMockBuilder('FileProcessor\Service\LogInfo', array('logger'))
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();
        $mockLogger = $this->getMockBuilder('Zend\Log\Logger', array('info'))
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();

        $serviceManager->setService('FileProcessor\Service\LogInfo', $mockLog);
        $serviceManager->setService('Zend\Log\Logger', $mockLogger);

        $data = 'I have data here';
        $this->fileProcessor->processData($data);
    }
}
```

This method also makes it possible to change expectations on the mock objects per test function. The `Processor` instance is constructed in `ProcessorTest::setUp()` which should be possible in this case.

Any way this does not solve your problem yet. I can see `Processor::getLoggerObj()` asks the `ServiceManager` for the service `'Processor\Service\LogInfo'` but your test class does not set this instance anywhere. Make sure you set this service in your test class like the following example.

```
$this->serviceManager->setService('Processor\Service\LogInfo', $processor);
```